# What waterproofing rating is sufficient for a navigation device for touring?

Tags: gps, navigation, smartphone-mount, android

I am exploring the possibility of using my phone as the main navigation device for touring. The phone (Pixel 2) is IP67-rated and I was planning to use it without any additional waterproofing, just attached to a Quad Lock handlebar mount.

I am now wondering whether serious rain is going to kill it or at least render temporarily unusable (touchscreen issues come to mind)?

Since I don't really want to find out the hard way, I thought I'd ask here in case any of you have relevant experience.

For comparison, my Edge 810 is IPX7 and has been fine in all sorts of conditions.

As an alternative to putting my main phone at risk, I am contemplating getting a cheap IP68-rated rugged phone (like [BV5800 Pro](http://www.blackview.hk/blackview-282/)). Not really sure whether it's likely to fair better (higher ingress protection rating) or worse (presumably cheaper construction).

P. S. Having looked into this further, I came across MIL-STD-810G. There are quite a few devices that advertise this, but I am not sure how much attention to pay to it (given that it's self-certification just like IP ratings are)?

P. P. S. There are phones that are specifically advertised as being operable with wet or gloved fingers (for example CAT S41). Not sure whether this in any way relates to MIL-STD-810G, or how much attention to pay to it. Would love your input.

Comment: If you have a Garmin Edge, why do  you need the phone on the bars for navigation?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus: *Much* prefer the functionality and the usability of OsmAnd over Edge 810 so am looking to replace the latter with the former. Have done some riding with the phone, and it's just about perfect for my needs. Weatherproofing is the only open question (even though, on paper, Pixel 2's IP67 is at least as good as Edge's IPX7 and IP68 would be even better).

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus: I wear a 920XT on my wrist for telemetry and track recording, so the Edge was just a mapping and navigation device (and, quite frankly, rather lacking at that).

Comment: From general observations, phones on handlebars suffer more from systemic failure due to ongoing vibrations or from coming loose and hitting the deck.   If you want any phone on display while riding, consider a top tube bag with a window on top, a handlebar bag with a clear map pocket on top, or even stick your phone in one of those jogging arm bands and put it on your forearm like an oversized watch.   Note most phones use much more power to have the screen on, so you will want a power source too.

Comment: I was curious about power sources, maybe a good answer can indicate if waterproofing is affected by charging cables, given touring context

Comment: In case anyone is contemplating a similar setup, in my testing I get ~7 hours of riding from the phone's 2700mAh battery.

Comment: I diagree with @Criggie on the toptube bag.  In sunlight you have to have the screen much brighter than with the phone naked because the clear plastic reflects the sunlight and it's *still* hard to read.  If you want to use it for navigation for any decent period of time, you can't have a flexible cover. (For short journeys or on my hybrid I do use the toptube bag sometimes).  My 3 year old phone is starting to misbehave now; it's been on the stem for thousands of km including a few crashes but has also been dropped many times when nowhere near a bike

Comment: The Edge800/810 themselves are not really as waterproof as they should be, they have a reputation for water getting in and corroding the USB port.  My 800 also died this way in a day of biblical rain in the dolomites.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easy bit - Touch screens don't usually work when wet, you can easily test it, sprinkle some water on the screen and see how it goes.

Because phones are high volume consumer goods designed as life style toys, not outdoor equipment, as far as IP ratings, I personally believe the claimed IP ratings are based on marketing need for a bigger number than the other guy, tempered by engineering squealing that IP99 is not a real rating, and Finance insisting at that price point they have a budget for X returns out of Y sales. The exception are devices sold as ruggedised.  Read the warranty fine print - I bet it excludes water damage.

IP67 is 1 meter for 30 minutes, but the test is done in factory conditions on a new phone, not after they are a few years olds and lost elasticity, and the user has contaminated the seals with dirt and dust. I had an IP67 phone with a single o-ring seal for the battery cover. I was happy to get it wet in the rain, but would not have left it on handle bars for hours in driving heavy rain while riding. Driven rain on a fast down hill could exceed the pressure of 1 meter of water.

I would also be concerned about "solar driven" moisture entering the phone. It gets wet, sun comes out and shines though the water onto the phone. The water close to the phone surface heats and vapor pressure increases, driving water vapour (not water droplets) into the phone. The expanding and contracting of air inside the phone from changing temperatures can also cause a negative pressure that sucks water in.

Although the risk is small, if you plan on riding with the phone on the bars in all weather, put it in a case or accept you might need to buy a new phone. But in a case, the touch screen may or may not work - you would need to test it.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer! I guess what I really want is an Android phone (or a small tablet -- don't really need cellular connectivity) built as outdoor equipment, not as a lifestyle toy. Assuming such a thing exists, I wonder how to tell the two categories apart? (Googling "ruggedised android phone" just turns up a bunch of reviews based on IP ratings and no real-world testing.)

Comment: @NPE By the time you're looking at buying a phone specially to mount on your handlebars to use as a navigation computer, why don't you just... buy an actual navigation computer? They are properly waterproof and you'll probably get double or more the battery life, which is important when touring.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I much prefer OsmAnd to any Garmin solution I have experience with (features, usability, map coverage etc). Even when I'm riding with my Edge, I often find myself pulling the phone out of my pocket just to find a nearby toilet, or a water fountain, or to read the Wikipedia article about the place I am passing, or to check a train timetable. At the same time I'm not using any Edge features that my phone doesn't offer (I already have a Garmin watch for all the ANT+ stuff etc). So my thinking is: "Why use two navigation devices when I can just use one, the phone?"

Comment: @NPE The point is that there are many manufacturers of GPS bike computers besides Garmin.

Comment: Upvoted but my take requires its own answer

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Fair point. Are there any manufacturers you'd recommend that I look at based on the description of how I use OsmAnd? Thanks!

Comment: You can use [this site](http://garmin.openstreetmap.nl/) to generate Garmin compatible maps from the OpenStreetMap data.

Comment: Would you say that all the caveats of IP ratings also apply to MIL-STD-810G (which also appears to be self-certification)? It seems that the spirit of MIL-STD-810G is that the device is _operable_ in various conditions (as opposed to merely _surviving_ them), but it's unclear whether it actually means that in marketing materials.

Comment: Its comes down to marketing - if 1 in 1000 consumers 'tests' their phone to extreme and one in 100 fail in those conditions, that is 1 in 100000 returns. If every second  user of outdoor/ruggedised product tests it to extreme and one in 10000 fail, that is a 1 in 5000 returns even though its 10 times more reliable it has 20 times the return rate. This is why ruggidised products are more expensive and more reliable.

Comment: @NPE Such things do exist.  The guides for a tour company I use have a very nice device that is a ruggedised android phone integrated with a proper camera.  They may be some sort of special order though since I too have been looking for such a thing with google, and like you have come up with slim pickings

Answer (score 5):

I use a Sony Xperia z3 compact as my bike computer/GPS, in all UK weather. It's described by the manufacturer as waterproof, but not for immersion, and I've never had any water ingress issues (even washing it up). You do have to be careful the seal is tight on the sim card slot.

As for using it in the rain, the touchscreen isn't completely useless, but it is rather unpredictable. I have navigated through storms with it but have also occasionally needed to stop, turn the screen off, wipe it, and turn it back on. This can be done without stopping (in an appropriate place) but an unlock code/pattern is quite hard to enter going along even if your phone is behaving perfectly. You may want to think about how you lock it (unlocked in proximity to your garmin might be good but I don't use anything Bluetooth at the moment).

A combination of rain and sweat dripping on areas of the screen that do stuff can be quite annoying even in light rain.

This particular phone has a special charge cable that can be used in the wet (in practice, no idea about in theory). For the new one I'll have to either top up when out of the rain (not great as I'm heading towards a dynamo system), protect the charging socket, or get wireless charging working, but battery life should be better than what I've got now.  My rides can be 12+ hours at the moment, and I'm looking at doing longer rides.  When navigating the screen dims to save battery, waking on touch

This phone is getting old and tired now; the replacement will be IP68 based on other specs.

---

**An update after [yesterday's ride](https://www.strava.com/activities/1766277402):**
The rain started in earnest while I was having lunch, so getting back on the bike everything got wet, and I decided to do some testing. On the handlebar mount the phone was glitchy and annoying but just about usable, so I tried the toptube bag (where I keep snacks).  With 5 minutes the clear plastic was completely fogged up.  The only way I could read even a small area of the screen was to press the plastic against the screen, and it fogged back up in seconds.  After missing a turning quite badly, and having to stop to check the map, I put it back on the bars. Normally if I miss a turning I can check the map without sopping if the road is clear.  It was still glitchy and annoying  but better than in the bag.  It seemed much worse in town or uphill, when going slower; the big drips off my helmet or mixed with sweat off my face are the worst for activating the touchscreen while an even film of water has much less of an effect.  Moving quickly the big drops fall behind the phone, and light rain seems to miss the screen.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience! This is exactly the sort of information I'm after. (If you already have some ideas for what IP68 device you might be getting, I'd love to hear about them.)

Comment: I'm thinking moto X4, based on the fact that anything else I can/want to afford is running an obsolete Android (waterproof phone seem to be behind others in terms of product updates).  But they're not easy to get hold of.  The blackview looks interesting too, though the BV7000 with its slightly smaller screen would suit me better at first glance

Comment: One more question: would you consider MIL-STD-810G relevant for this type of use (not really sure what this means in practice, given that it appears to be self-certification)? Also, there are some phones that are specifically advertised as being operable with wet or gloved fingers (for example CAT S41) - might be something to look into?

Comment: The sony has a glove mode and I didn't find it very useful.  I found it much better to get touchscreen-compatible bike gloves for winter (mine are the hi-vis version of [these](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/FDX-Cycling-Gloves-Windproof-Gel-Padded-Touchscreen-Full-Finger-Biking-Gloves/172049661988?hash=item280ef58024:m:m_MJ2b50uFIk8bJs_yYNTfQ) As for self-certifying to a standard few people understand, I'm sceptical (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIL-STD-810#Applicability_to_%22ruggedized%22_consumer_products) for example)

Comment: It's a bit of a long shot, but I've asked for device recommendations on  https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9606/android-device-to-use-in-wet-conditions

Comment: hardwarerecs post upvoted.  I may post an answer about the latest Sonys that are too expensive for me (XZ series, also the Z5 but that's running an old Android now) .  I'm still thinking about the charging aspect.

Comment: +1: Its reasonable to argue your experience invalidates my answer :)

Comment: @mattnz I think the answers complement each other quite well, heading for a conclusion of "you can, but...".  I'm thinking about a little windshield for my phone holder to improve touchscreen performance in the wet; it may also be a cue sheet holder.